# Change text for `option` in a `select` with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i´m trying to change a text for an option with jquery.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="change me">Change me</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').select2();
$(document).find('option[value="change me"]').text('Changed');
})
```

Well, nothing happends.
It´s important to change the text "live".
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmt22ffL/2/

Is this even possible?
I´m using Jquery plugin "Select2" for my select.

Comment: Actually it works: **https://jsfiddle.net/gmt22ffL/3/** Are you Let's see after loading Select2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works [perfectly fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gmt22ffL/3/). But let's try adding Select2 and see:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('option[value="change me"]').text('Changed');
  $('#mySelect').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="change me">Change me</option>
</select>
```

Swapping the lines work.

**Destroying and changing:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').select2();
  $('#mySelect').select2("destroy");
  $('option[value="change me"]').text('Changed');
  $('#mySelect').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="change me">Change me</option>
</select>
```

Comment: oh, easy fix. I like that =) Thank you!

Comment: Of corse, im waiting for it... I do have a new problem. In my actually code i load select2 way before this code runs. Is there away to unset Select2 and then add it again so that i can run this code. It seams like Select2 don´t like "Text changing" code?!

Comment: @Mjukis Lemme try both. Loading and changing, and also destroy, change and load.

Comment: @Mjukis To change the code dynamically: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830